# Como inserir usando SqlBulkCopy com EntityFramework

Tags: c#

Eu possuo um método que adiciona quase 2000 registros de uma vez,  eu estava usando o [Bulk Insert](http://entityframework-extensions.net/overview) e estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém essa extenção e paga.

Então eu resolvi usar o [SQLBulkCopy class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) porém estou com dificuldade em como usa-lo.

Eu tenho essa classe:

```
public class PessoaNotificacao
{
    public int PessoaNotificacaoId { get; set; }
    public int PessoaUnidadeId { get; set; }
    public int NotificacaoId { get; set; }
    public bool Visualizado { get; set; }
    public virtual Notificacao Notificacao { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaUnidade PessoaUnidade { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho um método com um foreach cria uma lista de inserção com aproximadamente 2000 registros, as tabelas que fazem ligações são essas:

```
  public class Notificacao
{
    public int Posicao { get; set; }
    public int NotificacaoId { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
}
```

e :

```
  public class Pessoa
{ 
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
}
```

atualmente eu faço a inserção dessa forma:

```
   foreach (PessoaUnidade pessoa in pessoas){

                var pessoaNotificacao = new PessoaNotificacao
                {
                    Visualizado = false,
                    PessoaUnidade = pessoa,
                    Notificacao = notificacao
                };
                _contexto.PessoaNotificacao.Add(pessoaNotificacao);
            }

            _contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Porém não sei como usar o `SqlBulkCopy`, estou atualmente estudando [ESTE EXEMPLO](https://gist.github.com/Boggin/763dbaf1b760bb298156) mas ainda não consegui nada. Caso algum consiga explicar como funcionaria essa inserção, ficaria grato.

Desde já muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: Se o Insert é com Entity posso entender que é de SQL para SQL? Se sim é a mesma base?

Comment: Os dados vao vir da mesma base, eu busca da tabela `Pessoa ` e vou inserir nessa `PessoaNotificacao`.

Comment: Você não sabe aplicar o SQLBulkCopy? você poderia passar da onde vem as informações e para onde vai? não faça comparação com Entity Framework, já de cara sua entidade tem uma agregação então precisa ser algo mais simples se colocar eu coloco um exemplo funcional, ou você quer um exemplo generico?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, entendi, vou tentar reformular a pergunta, vou dar um pesquisada a mais sobre o funcionamento do SqlBulkCopy, e que eu estava usando  o SqlBulkinsert mas ele parou de funcionar porque era pago. Vou dar um estudada e vou modificando a pergunta sem o exemplo do entityframework.

Comment: fiz uma edição, vou continuar estudando aqui para ve se consigo melhorar a pergunta, qualquer caso ela ainda fique confusa eu removo ela.

Comment: Você precisa gravar dentro da tabela `PessoaNotificacao` e os campos são:  PessoaNotificacaoId, PessoaUnidadeId,NotificacaoId, Visualizado ?

Comment: Exatamente @VirgilioNovic

Comment: O que eu posso propor é um exemplo seco com SQLBulkCopy com a conexão do Entity Framework! ai depois você adpata para o seu?

Comment: Bom, achei esta explicação
 ,acho que vai me ajudar :.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, se você propor um exemplo simples ja bastaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser utilizado a mesma conexão existente no [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), mas, isso não é regra se pode fazer uma própria, só que [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) exige um [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) para gravar o ***lote de informações*** em uma ***tabela***, um *exemplo de código inicial*:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
    SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection;
    connection.Open();

    SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
    copy.DestinationTableName = "PessoaNotificacaoId";
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add("PessoaNotificacaoId", "PessoaNotificacaoId");
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add("PessoaUnidadeId", "PessoaUnidadeId");
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add("NotificacaoId", "NotificacaoId");
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Visualizado", "Visualizado");


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("PessoaNotificacaoId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("PessoaUnidadeId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("NotificacaoId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Visualizado", typeof(bool));

    DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
    row1["PessoaNotificacaoId"] = 1;
    row1["PessoaUnidadeId"] = 1;
    row1["NotificacaoId"] = 1;
    row1["Visualizado"] = true;

    DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
    row2["PessoaNotificacaoId"] = 2;
    row2["PessoaUnidadeId"] = 2;
    row2["NotificacaoId"] = 2;
    row2["Visualizado"] = true;

    DataRow row3 = dt.NewRow();
    row3["PessoaNotificacaoId"] = 3;
    row3["PessoaUnidadeId"] = 3;
    row3["NotificacaoId"] = 3;
    row3["Visualizado"] = true;
    dt.Rows.Add(row1);
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);
    dt.Rows.Add(row3);

    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Nesse exemplo, pode ser feito aquela interação da pergunta e gerar os `Rows` desse [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), ***exemplo***:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow row = null;
foreach (PessoaUnidade pessoa in pessoas)
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["PessoaNotificacaoId"] = pessoa.Id;
    row["PessoaUnidadeId"] = pessoa.Id;
    row["NotificacaoId"] = notificacao.Id;
    row["Visualizado"] = false;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Se quiser converter com um código seria bem prático utilizar uma rotina assim:

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
       TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) 
           ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item)
             ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;

}
```

mas, não esqueça que o primeiro é o mais importante para a utilização do [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), inclusive para entender o processo.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Transferring Data Using SqlBulkCopy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy)
- [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [A workaround Sql Bulk Insert for Entity Framework 6.](https://gist.github.com/Boggin/763dbaf1b760bb298156)

Comment: Após ler uns exemplos na internet esse foi minha principal duvida, como utilizar a conexão existente no Entity Framework para fazer o Bulkinsert. Sua resposta me ajudou muito.

Comment: Interessante essa rotina para converter para DataTable, eu ja estava pensando em algo do tipo pois tenho posso ter que utlizar em mais de um metodo, então isso vai me ajudar muito. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Fiz e deu tudo certo com o primeiro método, tentei implementar o segundo e não o compreendi completamente, me parece que esse metodo funcionaria apenas para a copia de tabelas iguais, ou estou enganado ?

Comment: @WilliamCézar está enganado, talvez esteja fazendo errado, mas, esse método é para qualquer lista.

Comment: Eu estava usando de forma errada mesmo, agora entendi o funcionamento do metodo, o problema e que ele esta pegando todas as propriedades da minha classe inclusive umas Collections que não deveriam, e uns atributos virtuais.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), se os dados de cópia(origem) e destino estiverem na mesma instância do SQL Server, é mais rápido e eficiente utilizar o Transact SQL mesmo, por exemplo em uma procedure.

Outro ponto, você está usando um loop (foreach) para varrer todos os registros para gerar as modificações e depois inserir novamente no banco de dados.

Facilmente pode converter esse código para um `INSERT SELECT`, que será executado muito mais rapidamente, principalmente levando em conta a quantidade de registros.

Exemplos:
Exemplo simples para copiar todas as colunas

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Exemplo para copiar somente as colunas necessárias ou modificar algum valor

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Referência: [INSERT SELECT COMMAND](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: Conseguiria formular um exemplo para mim, estou pesquisando como fazer aqui, mas caso consiga me ajudaria.

Comment: Melhorei a resposta colocando alguns exemplos e uma referencia.