# Remover propriedades virtuais do TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()

Tags: c#, reflexão

Eu fiz [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238608/como-inserir-usando-sqlbulkcopy-com-entityframework) de como usar o SQLBulkCopy, o usuario @VirgilioNovic me mostrou um código que usa reflection para poder salvar qualquer tipo de lista, porém faço o `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` ele traz as propriedades `collection` e `virtual`,  que seriam de ligação, assim gerando um erro ao tentar salvar no baco.

Eu consegui remover os `IEnumerable` usando esse código:

```
var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))
                .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                .Where(l=> l.PropertyType == typeof(string) ||   
                   !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(l.PropertyType));
```

Porém não consegui remover as classes virtuais, essa e minha classe:

```
public class MensagemUnidade
{
        public int MensagemUnidadeId { get; set; }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public string Texto { get; set; }

        public ICollection<FotoMensagemUnidade> Fotos { get; set; }

        public int UnidadeId { get; set; }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

        public virtual Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
}
```

No caso eu já consegui retirar `Fotos`, porem precisava tirar `Cliente` e `Unidade` , deixando apenas `ClienteId` e `UnidadeId`, caso alguém saiba uma boa forma de se fazer isso ficaria grato.

EDIT:
Adicionando as propriedades ao `DataTable`

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)
                                         ?? prop.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Mas você precisa usar o `TypeDescriptor` e `PropertyDescriptor`?

Comment: Eu estava vendo a diferença entre eles Type e TypeDescriptor, eu só estou usando porque foi assim que o Victor me passou na outra  pergunta, como tenho pouco conhecimento ainda eu não mudei, estou estudando essa para ver o  que fica melhor, mas poderia usar qualquer outra coisa que tivesse o mesmo efeito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
  var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                .Where(l=> l.PropertyType == typeof(string) ||
                            !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(l.PropertyType) &&
                            (!l.GetMethod.IsVirtual));
```

Apenas troque `PropertyDescriptor` para `PropertyInfo` no `foreach` e use `Type` ao invés de `TypeDescriptor` -  `(typeof(T))`.

Comment: Eu tinha tentando assim, mas fala que PropertyDescriptor não tem um method GetMethod(),como tenho pouco experiência com reflexions eu não sei como usar corretamente.

Comment: não havia reparado, pensei se tratar de um PropertyInfo, vou alterar

Comment: Quando eu tentei fazer o foreach que esta no Edit ele deu erro falando que as objeto estava nulo, porém após o comentario do LINQ eu troquei para Type e funcionou perfeitamente, vou estudar a diferença entre essas propriedades, queria saber porque com TypeDescriptor me gerava erro.